# I need to retrieve data from a RESTful webservice using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, rest

i'm new to this RESTful webservice stuff so i'm asking if you can help me with this one.

I need to retrieve data from a restful webservice using jquery. now i know that i can do that using $.ajax or $.getJSON but the question is how can i do it if my restful webservice needs to enter username and password inorder to retrieve the data. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how your web service does authentication.

If it's token-based (via cookies or whatever), you'll need to invoke the login method of your service, get the token (or cookie, etc), and send that token with your future requests.

Other methods require other adjustments; authentication headers, etc. We can't tell you what you need unless we know what authentication method the service uses.

Comment: sorry i forgot to tell you that i need to put the username and password in the header. so basically i think its authentication headers. sorry i'm relatively new to this one.

Comment: Then you'll have to look up the spec for whatever headers you need to send, and use the "headers" parameter of $.ajax() to set them as appropriate (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

If you have to go to a page and *type in* a username and password before you can get your data, then it's not going to work.  It's not a service at all if this is the case.  Not every page is going to be able to be called via AJAX; usually they can't unless designed with AJAX in mind.  "REST" doesn't mean you can call any existing page effectively via AJAX.  It's a service that uses standard URIs and HTTP for it's communication, rather than [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) etc.  (That's a huge simplification, but not a bad one to start with.)

Are you in control of this "service"?  If so, you could:

- rewrite it so that it will accept username/password as query string parameters.  Or,
- assuming it's on the same site where the page came from where the AJAX is taking place, can you keep the user's session credentials in a cookie?  In many frameworks (.NET in my case) the framework helps you do this and it's relatively easy.  In the site I just deployed, there's REST AJAX all over the place and I don't do anything with Username/Passwords.  Just handle that up front if possible.

By the way, you're using SSL?  (That is, the site your going to, ajax or otherwise, begins with https?)

Comment: Typing in a username/password (and thus, probably using cookies for authentication) has nothing to do with whether or not something is a service.

Comment: @jvenema  Not quite sure what you're saying here.  The scenario makes sense to you, where a page is calling a service via ajax, and as a part of *that ajax service call* the human types in their user name and password?  Not to me.  Impossible actually.  My guess is that the OP is just starting to tip-toe into AJAX-REST land and is trying to get a few basic things straight.  I'm not 100% sure I gave him/her the exact best thoughts to help him/her past some misconceptions, but made my best guess.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you would have some sort of API key or session key.

Otherwise, you can just pass them as parameters in the call.   Just Renee that they are no longer secure.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the more complex yet more versatile ajax()-function that takes username and password as parameters. Note however that your users will be able to see the username and password in the source as well as in the request so this will compromise the security of your account.